# Want to create a VM instance in Google Cloud Platform by using CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, virtual-machine, google-cloud-sdk

Trying to create a VM instance in Google Cloud Platform. Getting error in the mentioned process. Trying to resolve it.

Error: **Could not fetch a resource:

- Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork': 'https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/xxx/regions/us/subnetworks/10.128.0.0/20'. The URL is malformed.**

Anyone, please guide me. My intention to make VM creation automated and make it simple by putting it all together in an automated Bash Script.

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that the URL is malformed. It probably because that "subnetwork" does not exist as you write it.

One way to fix it is to have a look in the documentation to know the right way to write the command. Also be sure that that subnet exist in your GCP project.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces

The easy way to avoid typos is to create the VM in the console the first time (you don't really have to create it, just start the form), at the bottom of the page you will see a line that says "Equivalent REST or command line", click in "command line" to see exactly the CLI command equivalent to the VM you are configuring. Use this command line in your CLI console or script.

[image: Equivalent REST or command line]

Clicking in the "command line" will return something like:

```
gcloud compute instances create VM_NAME \
    --network=NETWORK_NAME \
    --subnet=SUBNET_NAME \
    --zone=ZONE
```

with all the parameters already filled in for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alfons Muñoz, But I am looking for CLI commands and using them in to bash script. So we can make them automated.

Comment: no problem, pressing the link I circle in red will give you the command you are looking for. I can put the generic command but you need to replace the command with your network